uniformly sample a point in a triangle $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$
To choose a point with uniform distribution in a triangle $A:(1,0,0), B:(0,1,0), C:(0,0,1)$, my thought is to project the triangle onto X-Y plane first, and the projected triangle is $A:(1,0,0), B:(0,1,0), C':(0,0,0)$. Then sample a point $(x,y,0)$ in the projected triangle. Finally transform the point back to the triangle in the 3D space and the coordinate is $(x,y,1-x-y)$.
However, I feel like there are some problems with this approach. The areas of these two triangles are different. Yet the points before and after the tranfor have the same X- and Y-coordinates. Is this correct?

I would think to sample using barycentric coordinates.

Your method does work, because under the transformation $(x,y,0) \mapsto (x,y,1-x-y)$, areas remain proportional.  So in particular, the area of the triangle $\mathcal T(t) = \{(0,0), (t,0), (0,t)\}$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ is $t^2/2$, and under transformation, the triangle is mapped to $\mathcal T'(t) = \{(0,0,1), (t,0,1-t), (0,t,1-t)\}$ which has area $t^2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  So, provided that you select $(x,y)$ uniformly in the triangle $\mathcal T(1)$, then $(x,y,1-x-y)$ will be uniformly chosen in $\mathcal T'(1)$.
So the only remaining issue is how to choose such $(x,y)$ uniformly.  This is quite easy, since the conditional density of $Y$ given $X = x \in [0,1]$ is $$f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \mathbb 1 (0 \le y \le 1-x).$$  So in order for $(X,Y)$ to be uniform on $\mathcal T(1)$, we must choose $X \in [0,1]$ inversely proportional to the length of the support of $Y \mid X$; i.e., $$f_X(x) \propto 1-x,$$ hence $$f_X(x) = 2(1-x), \quad 0 \le x \le 1.$$  This is a $\operatorname{Beta}(1,2)$ distribution, so we can write
$$X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(1,2) \\
Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0, 1-X) \\
Z = 1 - X - Y.$$
The choice of $X$ is the most difficult part, but we can use the inverse transform sampling method because this particular density has an easily invertible CDF.  We choose $U \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$, then compute $X = 1 - \sqrt{1 - U}$, which will be $\operatorname{Beta}(1,2)$ distributed.  Since $U$ is symmetric on $[0,1]$, we can eliminate one operation and just let $X = 1 - \sqrt{U}$.
An alternative approach is to compute $(X,Y)$ uniform on the square $[0,1]^2$, and then employ a conditional:  if $X+Y > 1$, then let the selected point be $(1-X, 1-Y, X+Y-1)$, in effect rotating the point $(X,Y)$ about $(1/2, 1/2)$.  So this algorithm looks like this:
$$X' \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1) \\
Y' \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1) \\
(X,Y,Z) = \begin{cases}(X',Y',1-X'-Y'), & X' + Y' \le 1 \\
(1-X', 1-Y', X'+Y'-1), & X' + Y' > 1. \end{cases}$$
I'm not actually sure which approach is faster, but the square root in the first method may be more computationally expensive.

Your $X=1-\sqrt{U}$ look very close to the solution proposed in my answer.

Thank you so much! The proof is very clear

A more general answer, valid for any triangle.
A direct way to get a uniform distribution of points in a triangle $ABC$ is by using this barycentrical expression :
$$M=(1-\sqrt{r_{1}})A+(\sqrt{r_{1}}r_{2})B+\sqrt{r_{1}}(1-r_{2})C\tag{1}$$
where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
Otherwise said, as a two-step barycentration :
$$M=(1-\sqrt{r_{1}})A+\sqrt{r_{1}}\color{red}{\left[r_{2}B+(1-r_{2})C\right]}\tag{2}$$
The earliest version I have found of formulas (1)/(2) is in  this interesting ACM 2002 article : see its p. 814 with a graphical "heuristic proof" of formula (2) above given p. 815 that I reproduce here :

Formulas (1)/(2) are mentionned and established here.
Numerous other references and links like this one.
Remark :
My recent encounter with this issue is in this question.
My answer attests that I wasn't convinced at first look (maybe because they had been found by Chat GPT) : I was totally wrong.

Thank you so much!

You could sample uniformly a point in the square with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, by taking $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ uniformly and then map it to $(\max(x,y), \min(x,y))$.  Once you can sample uniformly in one triangle, it can be done in any triangle.
Similarly one can sample uniformly in an $n$-dimensional simplex, for small $n$. Not clear how expensive it would be to rearrange ( or test the order) if $n$ is say $10000$.
